# Laptop battery status abruptly reducing

Tags: laptop, battery

I am facing a problem with the battery status of my laptop. When I charge my laptop completely and remove from power, the battery remains full for some time and then it suddenly goes to around 13%. The time gap between this is also not constant, sometimes it will remain normal for 30 Minutes, sometimes it does that in 2-3 Minutes.

I have been facing this problem for a few months. Earlier it used to happen less often, now that happens every time. Because of it, I am not able to use my laptop without putting on charge. Also, I think this must be a software problem as battery power is not likely to change from 100 to 20% suddenly.

I searched the INTERNET for a solution but none of the suggested worked. I have tried upgrading battery driver, updated BIOS, nothing worked.

Can someone suggest solution?

Comment: How old is the laptop/battery?

Comment: @gronostaj about 2 years

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is consistant with a bad battery. Some of the cells are damaged, it is dying. You should replace it.

Comment: Well, what is the average life of a battery? My battery is about 2 years old, so is it normal for this to happen or is it because of improper use?

Comment: I do not know what the average life span is, but improper use or faulty manufacture could be the reason. But the drop to 13 % sounds like a few cells are dead. Like an 8 cell battery which has all but 1 cell dead(~13 % per cell). Sounds excessive but it can be due to design choices.